# Javascript .getElementsByClassName isn't working

Tags: javascript, dom

This code has no errors in console.log, but it doesn't display class name as it should.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("abc").onmouseover =  function(){mouseOver()};
 function mouseOver(){
 abc.innerHTML = "Class name " + abc.className;
 }
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("abc")` returns a collection of html elements, you should loop through each of these elements in the collection

Answer (score 2):

The `.getElementsByClassName()` routine returns a **list** of elements. You cannot directly add event handlers to all elements via the list as you're attempting to do. You have to iterate explicitly:

```
var abc = document.getElementsByClassName("abc");
for (var i = 0; i < abc.length; ++i) {
  // ...
}
```

For your purposes, doing that with the `Array.prototype.forEach` method makes a little more sense, though it looks odd:

```
var abc = document.getElementsByClassName("abc");
[].forEach.call(abc, function(element) {
  element.onmouseover = function() {
    element.innerHTML = "Class name: " + element.className;
  };
});
```

Using `.forEach` ensures that the event handler works properly using a local variable (`element`) private to each invocation of the loop callback.

Comment: Could also just use `this` inside the event handler.

Comment: @FelixKling yes sure; I was too lazy to verify that `onfoo` type handlers would have `this` correctly bound all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. So you will have to bind the onmousever event with each child object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

You can try like this.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("abc")

for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onmouseover =  function(){mouseOver(i)};
}

function mouseOver(index){

   document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[index -1].innerHTML = "Class name " + document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[index -1].className;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  mouse over me
</div>
```

Edited Answer based on the provided html in comment

```
<html> <head>   </head> <body> <h1 class="abc">Hello everyone</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("abc"); for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) { elements[i].onmouseover = function(){mouseOver(i)}; } function mouseOver(index){ document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[index -1].innerHTML = "Class name " + document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[index -1].className; } </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this don't work on chrome. I tried it on jsfiddle and it did work. I don't know what to do...

Comment: its working for me on chrome. could you post your code?

Comment: <html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
  
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("abc")

for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onmouseover =  function(){mouseOver(i)};
}

function mouseOver(index){

   document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[index -1].innerHTML = "Class name " + document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[index -1].className;
}
   
   
    
    
      </script>  
  
  
 </head>
 <body>
 
  <h1 class="abc">Hello everyone</div>
 

 </body>
</html>

Comment: you need to put your script tag just before closing the body tag and put a ; before using for loop

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome :)